# SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to myUrl (port 80) after 7000ms - Jsoup

Tags: android, timeout, jsoup, user-agent, socket-timeout-exception

In Android I have multi threads that performs `HTML` parsing using `Jsoup`.
My connection code is:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(this.userAgent).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
```

where `this.userAgent` equals to the latest Mozilla user agent - `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"`.

Now how come I get this `SocketTimeoutException` with a parameter of 7000ms when I specify a 10000ms?
Also I tried to set the timeout to be infinite `timeout(0)` and I still get this `Exception`.

**LogCat**:

```
05-11 13:49:45.582 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.songlyrics.com/23.252.119.106 (port 80) after 7000ms
05-11 13:49:45.582 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster.GetSongLyricsDotComResults.getParsedDocument(GetSongLyricsDotComResults.java:183)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster.GetSongLyricsDotComResults.getSongLyricsDotComResults(GetSongLyricsDotComResults.java:87)
05-11 13:49:45.583 11796-12561/com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster W/System.err:     at com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster.GetSongLyricsDotComResults.run(GetSongLyricsDotComResults.java:42)
```

`getParsedDocument()` performing my `Jsoup` connection.

**EDIT**:
Just leave the mismatched ms.

Why I get this `SocketTimeoutException` even when i set the timeout to be infinite?

**EDIT#2**:

Got to say that I'm working with `Jsoup` `API` a long time and never user `UserAgent` or `Timeout` and I decided to add them. The problems started to occur after I added the `UserAgent` and `Timeout` to my connection methods.

Comment: `Jsoup.connect(url)....` Please tell the value of url.

Comment: @greenapps Actually I dont know the value. There are **a lot** of values. You're telling me the `Exception` is thrown because of Malformed URLs?

Comment: @greenapps But the urls are of the form of `www.lyricsplanet.com/66.240.174.52`,

Comment: Url's should begin with http://.

Comment: And why has your url a host name and an ip? That looks invalid.

Comment: It is silly to say that you dont know the value. And then you could log them before and after use.

Comment: @greenapps So I need to just append `"http://"` to the start of the URL? and I don't know why the ip is shown; In fact I don't really know if it's the URL that been parse. It's just the one that shows up in my `IOException` stack trace.

Comment: @greenapps On further checkup, the URLs are just fine. Starts with `http://` and without any ip.

Comment: Try that url in a browser on your device. Well that looks problematic for you as you dont know the url ;-).

Comment: @greenapps I know now. It's a good well formatted URL. I tried in the browser of my device(which I debug on it) and I get the `HTML` document.

Comment: @greenapps Also can you see my edit please?

Comment: What should i see? Please be more specific.

Comment: `The problems started to occur after I added the UserAgent and Timeout to my connection methods.`. Well then you know how you can restore all.

Comment: @greenapps LOL. I tried it ;). Didn't worked either.

Comment: @greenapps Maybe `Jsoup` became corrupted?

Comment: Restart your computer. Take a break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111668/discussion-between-god-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps Well I very appreciate your help man. Cheers. I really need a break I guess. Maybe tomorrow `Jsoup` will not let me down.

Comment: @greenapps One last question. What would be the optimal `timeout` for a `Jsoup` connection considered there are many `Thread`s parsing? Because I see 1000ms is not enough but infinite is not working. So what to set my timeout to be optimal? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

> I have multi threads that performs HTML parsing using Jsoup. 
>   (...)
>   The problems started to occur after I added the `UserAgent` and `Timeout`

The root cause may not come from the fact of adding the `UserAgent` and `Timeout`.

Check that

- too many threads don't send requests to the server at the same time using the same IP adress.
- there's a "nice" delay between each requests (between 2000ms and 5000ms is a good start)
- the delay between requests is random
- they aren't too many connections opened from the host running the threads.

Comment: Thanks about the answer but running today the app seems to work perfectly fine without any `Exception`s thrown at me ;). I guess something with my computer and the network I used was off yesterday.

Comment: Though running the app with finite timeout of 60 - 60 seconds produces the `Exception` ;(.

Answer (score 0):

The **Wifi network which i connected has no internet** so i go this Exception.Then I Connected to Another Network which has Internet Then I got Response From the Server.